# Symfony 2 trouble wih entity-class mapping is invalid in ide.c9.io

Tags: php, symfony, cloud9-ide

I get this error in my bill.php entity and item.php when trying to create a relationship one-to-many

```
[Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Zero\BillingBundle\Entity\Bill' mapping is invalid:
* The association Zero\BillingBundle\Entity\Bill#items refers to the owning side field Zero\BillingBundle\Entity\Item#bill which does not exist.
```

these are my files:

- [item.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/94uyghil3sxqfj8/Item.php?dl=0)
- [bill.php](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ppcbzpjtbz5trsi/Bill.php?dl=0)

I've already read similar answers, but I don't find a concret solution.

Thanks for help

Comment: Could you try with `app/console cache:clear && app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`?

Comment: It looks like you are missing an asterisk from the docblock for `$bill`. `/*` should be `/**`.